# Edit Android Soft keyboard opened in Webview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `Webview` in which a URL is loaded which includes input fields. I have enabled soft keyboard through `WebView.requestFocusFromTouch()`.

`I want to add the Tab button on keyboard to change focus through input fields, is there a way to edit the keyboard displayed and catch it's action ?`